# Alias and executable file

Tags: command-line, alias

I have `lmp_fedora` executable file located in `/src`. I use this command:

```
mpirun -np 4 lmp_fedora < in.stdinfile
```

to execute the job. However it is only able to run if I copy `lmp_fedora` into the same directory where I am launching the job. I compiled a alias:

```
echo 'alias lmp_fedora=/home/MyUSERNAME/liggghts/src/lmp_fedora' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and my motive is to be able to execute `lmp_fedora` from any directory. Is the above correct? and if yes, now I am stuck on what should my new job submit command be for that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your alias can be called `normal` alias: it replace command at the beginning of the command line but not in the middle of it. To create `global` alias you need switch your shell from bash to zsh. See [shells comparison](http://www.slideshare.net/jaguardesignstudio/why-zsh-is-cooler-than-your-shell-16194692) for more information.

If you still want to work with bash, you probably don't need an alias at all. You need to adjust PATH variable where shell searches for executables. If you do something like

```
export PATH=/home/MyUSERNAME/liggghts/src/:$PATH
```

you will be able to run `lmp_fedora` without any aliases. I think that wrapping it with `mpirun`will work too but I can't test it.

Comment: Here is [manual reference](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect12). Your answer could be right. If you like, you could add this reference.

Comment: Kakadu, many thanks and I really appreciate, changing PATH variable did the trick.

Comment: @TheoScore you can accept the question than.