# Alias syntax for mpirun

Tags: command-line, alias

I execute my jobs in terminal using:

```
mpirun -np 4 lmp_fedora < in.stdinfile
```

Now I want to create a permanent alias `run` so that I can just input the command:

```
run < in.stdinfile
```

from any directory in the terminal to execute my jobs. What is the syntax for the alias or the environment variable?

Comment: Apologies for removing your thanksgivings from your question, but as it stands [the community prefers the questions to have the lowest noise-ratio as possible in their body](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021); I don't really agree with this, but this is how it stands; However, *I think* that reporting them in the comments section, if you're willing, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the alias would be:

```
alias run='mpirun -np 4 lmp_fedora'
```

The canonical way to add an user-defined local alias is to put it into `~/.bashrc`; you can directly add it to `~/.bashrc` using this command, which will append it to the end of the file:

```
echo "alias run='mpirun -np 4 lmp_fedora'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then you can run `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes in your current `bash` instance:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @TheoScore I'm glad to have helped you. Since you're a new user, please consider accepting, for each of your question (i.e. [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645043/alias-and-executable-file) also), the answer that helped you the most; this is a way to highlight which answer worked for you (for future visitors) and to thank the answerer, giving him 15 points of reputation (you'll also get 2 points of reputation from each acceptance) [cont]

Comment: [cont] Furthermore, when you'll have more reputation (I think 15 it's enough), consider also upvoting such accepted answers, along with all the other helpful answers you received to your questions; that's how you indicate that you deem that such answers were useful (in this case to pursue your scope).